# Website buttons not working when viewed by mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile

My website works fine when viewed on desktop, however when viewing the same website on mobile, the buttons don't work.

They were working in a previous version however. I've hardly changed the HTML/CSS and have been mainly working on the JavaScript of the page.

The website in question: http://www.bodmascalc.com

Also I know there are a few bugs, and the code isn't amazing. I'm just looking for suggestions as to why the buttons aren't working when viewed via mobile.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In the future, I recommend [not posting a link to your website](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it) and instead replicating the problem in e.g. JSFiddle, so that the question may be useful for other people in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to fix your `power` function. I checked the console, and `**` was throwing an error. I replaced it with the built in `Math.pow` function. Good luck!

```
function power(sum, b) {
  writeSumPart(sum);

  b = sum.split('^');
  tempAnswer = Math.pow(b[0], b[1]);
  writeTempAnswer(tempAnswer);
  return Math.pow(b[0], b[1]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you!! This was the solution :)

Comment: Glad I could help.